# Différence entre "éros" et "agapé"

Tags: grec

En grec on fait une différence entre :

> Éros (erotas) désignant l'amour charnel et agapé (agape) désignant l'amour spirituel.

À propos, le mot érotisme (parmi d'autres mots) provient du dieu de la mythologie grecque Éros. Quels mots existent pour désigner cette différence en français ? J'ai vu

> l'amour naturel, la concupiscence, le plaisir corporel

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mots_grecs_pour_dire_amour

Y a-t-il d'autres ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love

Answer (score 0, accepted):

À propos du terme « érotisme » la remarque suivante que l'on relève dans le TLFi est très instructive sur la façon dont l'homme instruit perçoit la place de celui-ci parmi les autres termes de la famille des mots dédiés à la sexualité.

> Rem. ,,L'érotisme se distingue parfois mal de la pornographie, et il embarrasse ainsi les censeurs. Pourtant, il nuance le but commun, procurer le plaisir génital, en l'enveloppant d'esthétique, en suggérant plus qu'il n'impose. Entre ce raffinement et la brutale obscénité, la différence est aussi grande, a-t-on pu écrire, qu'entre un vin de grand cru et un autre très épais`` (BERTR.-LAPIE 1970).

En ce qui concerne **l'amour érotique** les trois termes suivants en supplément de ce premier sont libres de connotations :  « **le plaisir charnel** », « **les plaisirs de la chair** », « **l'amour charnel** ». Cependant, le terme « **la baise** », qui pour moi reste un terme à éviter, parlera certainement mieux à un public important. Le terme « **amour physique** » en est un autre que je ne connais pas mais que je crois être d'un registre de langue correct.

Pour ce qui est de l'amour spirituel je crois qu'il y a des problèmes de point de vue; une authorité anglaise sur la question considère qu'il existe quatre sortes d'amour en grec  and « agape » serait un amour d'ordre strictement religieux ([Lewis Doodle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WReLIE08Dnc)).

- "Philia" or Friendship
- "Agape" or  christian love
- "Eros"  or love between the sexes
- "Storge" or Affection

Néanmoins, la définition du dictionnaire « [L'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/amour-spirituel/) » défini cet amour particulier à sa façon et donne un terme qui  décrit une variante ayant la caractéristique d'être l'idéalisation de cet amour ; c'est le terme « **amour platonique** ».

> Véritable amour de la personne pour ce qu'elle est, pour son âme. L'amour spirituel est l'amour exprimé par deux âmes sœurs qui va au-delà de l'attirance physique puisqu'il est souvent considéré comme un amour platonique.

Je ne suis pas d'accord sur la définition de ce dictionnaire parce que je la trouve trop restrictive ; en particulier, l'amour chrétien me semble n'être dans aucune autre catégorie que l'amour spirituel et la religion ne parle pas d'âme sœur ; il n'est pas question dans la religion chrétienne de considérations générales sur les relations intimes sauf dans le cadre du mariage et cela n'est qu'une petite partie de ce qui est appelé l'amour chrétien.

En français l'amour spirituel n'est pas limité au seul domaine de la philosophie religieuse ni de l'amitié, mais inclus l'amour amical, l'amour filial, l'amour paternel, …

Tout cela est plutôt insaisissable et je vais me limiter à l'aspect de l'amour spirituel de la sorte particulière qui existe entre les sexes sur la base d'une relation sexuelle puisque il existe dans la question « Différence entre 'éros' et 'agape' » une opposition semi voilée. Pour ce qui est de cet amour hors d'une relation conjugale il n'y a pas de terme propre. Je ne suis pas conscient de sa définition ; des termes comme « petite amie » pourraient tendre à laisser penser que cet amour est assimilable à de l'amitié telle que conçue en général, mais je ne sais pas ; il est plus probable qu'il s'agit déjà d'un amour très similaire à l'amour entre mari et femme.  Lorsqu'une telle relation est consacrée par les liens du mariage on parle d'**amour conjugal** et il n'y a dans ce terme aucune allusion à la sexualité.

Comment: *...amour conjugal et il n'y a dans ce terme aucune allusion à la sexualité.*: Pourtant lorsque la dimension sexuelle est absente du mariage, celui-ci peut être juridiquement annulé, ce qui est une procédure différente du divorce.

Comment: @mouviciel On attaque là des questions difficiles de psychologie sur lesquelles je n'ai pas d'information et peu d'opinions ; pour ne pas dépasser le cadre du point de vue religieux la prescription de ce qu'est l'amour conjugal considère la chose dans son ensemble sans impliquer l'érotisme, mais évidemment, on le sais, la religion n'est pas tout.

Comment: agape is not Christian love per se. That is a misnomer. https://www.universalis.fr/encyclopedie/agape/

Comment: @Lambie Are you on the rampage? You gave me a negative vote for that? You are entirely wrong. Two clear proofs of that: 1/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaVaGGpeQKM&t=20s 2/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agape  (In Christianity, agape (/ɑːˈɡɑːpeɪ, ˈɑːɡəˌpeɪ, ˈæɡə-/;[1][2] from Ancient Greek ἀγάπη (agápē)) is unconditional love, "the highest form of love, charity" and "the love of God for man and of man for God".[3] This is in contrast to philia, brotherly love, or philautia, self-love)

Comment: I know all the Greek words for love.  I actually took a course on this and went to a Jesuit university. "agape, Greek agapē, in the New Testament, the fatherly love of God for humans, as well as the human reciprocal love for God. In Scripture, the transcendent agape love is the highest form of love and is contrasted with eros, or erotic love, and philia, or brotherly love. In John 3:16, a verse that is often described as a summary of the Gospel message, agape is the word used for the love that moved God to send his only son for the world’s redemption.

Comment: The term necessarily extends to the love of one’s fellow humans, as the reciprocal love between God and humans is made manifest in one’s unselfish love of others. See also charity." End quote  https://www.britannica.com/topic/agape And eros is not love between the sexes. I'm sure many of the Greek machos having sex with ephebes experienced plenty of **eros**. eros is sexual "love" or strong attraction. And philia is brotherly love.

Comment: @Lambie That is christian love, love as defined only by religious precepts, as said in the video; that is exactly what I am saying, "amour chrétien". You have no point, you refute nothing, you merely ramble on, even if learnedly.

Comment: agape may include Christian love but it's **definition** is not "Christian love*. These Greek words were around BEFORE the Bible even existed. I have always found it impossible to have any discussion with you as you take every comment and make it something isn't.

Comment: @Lambie "Agape" is "Love in the christian sense", that is what is said in the video (by a churchman); what is that if not christian love?

Comment: I'm objecting to the list in your answer as if it were the be all and end all of these words.

Comment: @Lambie It is not *my* equivalence, but that of an expert : Clive Staples Lewis (29 November 1898 – 22 November 1963) was a British novelist, poet, academic, medievalist, literary critic, essayist, lay theologian, broadcaster, lecturer, and Christian apologist. He held academic positions at both Oxford University (Magdalen College), 1925–54, and Cambridge University (Magdalene College), 1954–63.

Comment: Christian apologist says it all. This one is less tendentious: http://palimpsestes.fr/metaphysique/livreI/29ter-aimer.html Fyi, the word Christian in English is capitalized, always.

Comment: @Lambie Do you think that "on le traduit par « charité »" takes into account that objectivity you are suddenly concerned with ? Just another approximation… The love for God is again "Christian love", also disinterested love, but that is not included in charity; it is, however included in the sense of "agape".